# Windows 8.1 share doesn't work when Print Screen is added

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to implement some logical to share the image of my webView and some extras informations. If I do that without capture screen, it works perfectly:

```
   private async void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (await GetShareContent(e.Request))
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Request.Data.Properties.Title))
            {
                e.Request.FailWithDisplayText("Nenhum título adicionado");
            }
        }
    }

private async Task<bool> GetShareContent(DataRequest request, StorageFile file)
        {
            bool succeeded = false;
            string text = "Dados do Arquivo:" + Environment.NewLine + webViewModel.Name;
            string dataPackageText = text;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataPackageText))
            {
                DataPackage requestData = request.Data;
                requestData.Properties.Title = "Target";
                requestData.Properties.Description = webViewModel.Name;
                requestData.SetText(dataPackageText);
                succeeded = true;
            }
            else
            {
                request.FailWithDisplayText("Não há nada para compartilhar");
            }
            return succeeded;
        }
```

But, if I try the same thing justing adding the captured image, it doesn't work, doesn't show any Excepetion, just the message: "Não há nada para compartilhar agora" (There's nothing to share right now)

I don't know what is going on. The code that doesn't work:

```
private async void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile file = await captureScreen();

    if (await GetShareContent(e.Request, file))
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Request.Data.Properties.Title))
        {
            e.Request.FailWithDisplayText("Nenhum título adicionado");
        }
    }
}

 private async Task<StorageFile> captureScreen()
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(webView, (int)webView.Width, (int)webView.Height);

            Image myImage = new Image();
            myImage.Source = renderTargetBitmap;

            var file = await App.rootDir.CreateFileAsync("screenCapture.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
                byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();
                encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                     BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                                     (uint)webView.Width, (uint)webView.Height,
                                     96, 96, bytes);

                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }

            return file;
        }
```

I though it could be happening because the image was not read when the share is called, but I'm using await as it should be. And my jpeg is created perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnDataRequested` callback needs to take a deferral, using [`DataRequest.GetDeferral`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datarequest.getdeferral), when calling asynchronous APIs.

```
private async void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRequestDeferral deferral = e.Request.GetDeferral();

    // Code to do screen capture...

    deferral.Complete();
}
```

But, per MSDN, "[the share operation] function must return a DataPackage object within 200ms to prevent the operation from timing out".  It is definitely possible for the screen capture to take longer than 200 ms. Use the [`DataPackage.SetDataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.setdataprovider) for operations that may take longer such as screen capture.

```
private void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataPackage requestData = e.request.Data;
    requestData.Properties.Title = "Target";
    requestData.Properties.Description = webViewModel.Name;
    // Set up the data provider for a long running share operation...
    requestData.SetDataProvider(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap, OnDeferredRequestedHandler);
}

private async void OnDeferredRequestedHandler(DataProviderRequest providerRequest)
{
    // Again, get a deferral as an asynchronous method is called
    DataProviderDeferral deferral = providerRequest.GetDeferral();

    // Code to do screen capture...

    deferral.Complete();
}
```

The [`Share content source sample`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84/sourcecode?fileId=43981&pathId=49193621) on MSDN shows how this can be performed in full detail.